# doctype declaration is causing internet explorer to throw a SSL warning

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl, doctype

IE is throwing an error "do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securrely." On investigation, removing the doctype removes the error.  There are no other calls to http content in the page.

How can I declare the doctype with a https connection or in some other way get around IE's problem? This is my doctype statement:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

I don't get any warnings in any other browsers, just IE.

Comment: Show the doctype you are using please.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: < ! DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "h t t p : //www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" >

Comment: Ive gone through the page and i think its a call to a flash uploader thats breaking the ssl. removng the doctype dec stops that happening, but isn't the root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual cause of this was the http:// codebase calls in the js calls to flash.  i changed these to https and the warnings went away.

Answer (score 4):

1. Make sure that no external .js file is called using http://
2. You can use "//" instead of "https://" when referencing resources